# How do I call a function from Angular controller to Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

First off, I'm pretty new with **Laravel+Angular** which basically why I'm here.

I have this function delete from my Angular controller that uses `$http.delete()` to call the Laravel controller.

```
$scope.deleteJob = function(index) {
    $scope.loading = true;

    var job = $scope.jobs[index];

    $http.delete('/api/job/' + job.jobId)
        .success(function() {
            $scope.job.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.loading = false;
        });;
};
```

With this route I should get to the Laravel controller:

```
Route::resource('api/job','ApiJobController');
```

Which i have defined a function to delete from my eloquent DB

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    App\Job::destroy($id);
}
```

I don't know what I miss but everytime I invoke `deleteJob(index)` I get a Server Error.

```
DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/job/20 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried using `/api/job/destroy/`, still getting 500

Comment: what is the response  error?

Comment: @aseferov Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Answer (score 0):

Try with this route

```
Route::get('/api/job','ApiJobController@destroy');
```

Or you can use

```
$http({
  method: 'DELETE',
  url: '/api/job/' + job.jobId
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: quick question, what if i have another function to call from ApiJobController? will this route limit my access to function destroy only? thanks

Comment: your method type and url will decide with function need to to call, please check laravel REST API, As you are using resource routes

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`App\Job::find($id)->delete();`

Comment: still returning 500. i think the problem is that i cannot communicate with the laravel controller jobController@destroy, and please have some brief explaination of the code you want me to try thanks! @sahil09

Comment: @HardSpocker can you show the code inside of your destroy($id) method in Job model

Comment: you mean THE model? im using eloquent model it doesnt contain anything